# How do I know when an AAAA record is required?

Tags: domain-name-system, ipv6

I'm trying to wrap my head around DNS. My biggest issue right now is understanding when an AAAA record is required.

Recently, I was asked by a colleague to point a subdomain from **Server A** to **Server B**.
So, I created the subdomain on **Server B** and edited the DNS records (via TinyDNS which is a text file based DNS system) on **Server A**, which has the main domain on it, to point the subdomain at **Server B**.

This worked fine, I and a few other colleagues could see and access the subdomain.
However, the colleague that asked me to point the subdomain could not.

It turned out that I also needed to add AAAA records to the DNS in order to "fully" point the subdomain at **Server B's** IPv6 address.

---

So what I don't get is, how could you tell when you might need to add AAAA records to the DNS? Is it a good rule of thumb to always add them?
And, most importantly, what could be the reason behind my colleague not being able to see the subdomain when I and a few others could?

Comment: Your colleague didn't have IPv4 connectivity, that is why he couldn't reach the server.

Comment: @TeroKilkanen Ah, I see, thanks, I wasn't aware that someone could not have IPv4 connectivity. That would make sense.

Comment: IPv4 addresses ran out some time ago, and even bad workarounds like "carrier grade" NAT are reaching their limits. The number of people without IPv4 connectivity will only grow, and sooner or later IPv4 will be a distant memory.

Comment: @MichaelHampton That is valuable to know, thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 4):

A records are for IPv4, AAAA records are for IPv6.

It is now 2020 so yeah, AAAA records should be mandatory.